# Updating rails 6 params with a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, patch, ruby-on-rails-6

Hello I have a lists of invoices that belong to a business and also the business belongs to a user, I am trying to have a button (link to) on a table in which all the invoices are listed for the user to be able to update the status of the invoice.
Pretty much if the user hits the link it will change from paid: true to paid: false and viseversa.
here are the routes:

```
  resources :businesses do
    resources :invoices
  end
```

Here is the section of the table in which the link is:

```
<% if invoice.paid %>
   <td><%= link_to "Mark as Not Paid", business_invoice_path(current_user, invoice), method: 'put', data: {paid: false} %></td>
<% else %>
   <td><%= link_to "Mark as Paid", business_invoice_path(current_user, invoice), method: 'put', data: {paid: true}%></td>
<% end %>
```

Note: The paid column is a boolean on the db

Answer (score 0):

Since, the paid column is present on Invoice, it is much better if you handle it at the controller or model level instead of getting the value from the form.

Remove if else conditions and combine it as below:

```rb
<%
  invoice_text = invoice.paid ? 'Mark as Not Paid' : 'Mark as Paid'
%>
<td><%= link_to invoice_text, business_invoice_path(invoice), method: :put %></td>
```

In the `Business::InvoicesController` you can write the logic in `update` like this:

```rb
Business::InvoicesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_invoice

  def update
    # TODO: find the business using the invoice
    # have a check in place to authorize the 
    # transaction (if invoice belongs a business which 
    # belongs the current_user or not, if not then raise Unauthorized error)
    # if business does belongs to the current_user then proceed to next step

    # invert the value of paid column based on existing value
    @invoice.update(paid: !@invoice.paid)
  end

  private

  def set_invoice
    @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

With logic above, you can forget about maintain/finding the value of paid column since you have an option to revert the value of paid to `true` and back to `false`. Also, that I assumed you are using Devise for authentication.

Comment: This code assumes there will be no other update actions. What if the invoice also has an other column that can be updated? In that case the paid column will also be updated...

Comment: I agree, the assumption is because OP did not mention any other action on the invoice.

Comment: I agree with the _general_ implementation of this. There could be a case to use a [`member`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-member-routes) route for this.

Comment: yeah, now I think member route is much better option for this feature. thanks for pointing it @SarahMarie